# How to get a list of receivers from android manifest?

Tags: android, android-manifest, receiver

I've been looking everywhere, but haven't found a solution. How can I get a list of receivers registered in Android manifest?

Answer (score 1):

To get receivers you must know intent filter and use [PackageManager#queryBroadcastReceivers()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryBroadcastReceivers%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)